# How to reverse time on paths

Tags: 3d, asymptote, paths, transformation

I am trying to draw a circle and its projection a plane. I can draw a circles on one plane an its projection on the other plane. Now i want to draw all possible perpendiculars from every circle's point to the corresponding point of the ellipsis. I know i can use

```
surface extrude(path3 p, path3 q);
```

after. There is a warning in the tutorial:

> This can cause problems if the two paths do not have the same length (in the sense
>   of path times); in general, this function should be used only with care.

but this is apparently not my case. My case is a little bit trickier. Here is a MWE

(**Important**: to compile it, use

```
pdflatex  -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

option. This is how asypictureB works: it needs `-shell-escape`):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{asypictureB}


%============================================================
\begin{document}




\begin{asypicture}{name=test}
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 16;
import three;
import solids;
size(3.8cm, 0);
currentprojection=orthographic((0,3,0));
//%============ Define objects =======
real VarPhi=40; //Angle of cutting plane
real a = 10; //The plane size

//Horizontal plane
path3 xyplane = (a,a,0)--(-a,a,0)--(-a,-a,0)--(a,-a,0)--cycle;

//Rotated plane
path3 xyplaneRotated = rotate(angle=-VarPhi, u=(a,a,0), v=(a,-a,0))*xyplane;

//Cylinder radius
real Radius = 5;

//Circle on the rotated plane
path3 CircleOriginal = shift(-Z*a*tan(VarPhi))*rotate(angle=VarPhi, Y)*circle(c=O, r=Radius, normal=Z); 

//Circle's projection = ellipse
path3 CircleProjection = rotate(angle=180, Y)*xscale3(cos(VarPhi))*circle(c=O, r=Radius, normal=Z);

//%============ Drawing ===================
//Axes
draw(O--10X, red);
draw(O--10Y, blue);
draw(O--10Z, green);

//Planes
draw(surface(xyplane),black+opacity(.1));
draw(xyplane,black+linewidth(.1));
draw(surface(xyplaneRotated),black+opacity(.1));
draw(xyplaneRotated,black+linewidth(.1));


//Circular bases
draw(CircleOriginal, red);
draw(CircleProjection, red);

//Surface
draw(extrude(CircleOriginal, CircleProjection),surfacepen=emissive(white));


\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure, but it produces the picture above with

```
path3 CircleOriginal = shift(-Z*a*tan(VarPhi))*rotate(angle=VarPhi, Y)*circle(c=O, r=Radius, normal=Z);
```

This looks strange and counter-intuitive for me. I think I should raise the circle UP, not DOWN. So I would understand if it were `shift(Z*a*tan(VarPhi))` (with PLUS) instead of `shift(-Z*a*tan(VarPhi))` (with MINUS). However, this doesn't produce the correct result with plus:

[image]

**Question: Why doesn't the circle lay on the rotated plane, but in fact is higher than it?**

It is visually parallel to the rotated plane, so there mistake is not in the rotation (`rotate(angle=VarPhi, Y)`), but in the shift (`shift(-Z*a*tan(VarPhi))`). What do I do wrong?

Comment: I am stupid. Just added `rotate(angle=180, Y)` to CircleProjection definition. The minor question is still up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point is that all trigonometric functions in asymptote need radians, but all rotation angles are in degrees. Taking care of it fixes the situation:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{asypictureB}


%============================================================
\begin{document}




\begin{asypicture}{name=test}
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 16;
import three;
import solids;
size(3.8cm, 0);
currentprojection=orthographic((0,3,0));
//%============ Define objects =======
real VarPhi=40*pi/180;
real a = 10;

path3 xyplane = (a,a,0)--(-a,a,0)--(-a,-a,0)--(a,-a,0)--cycle;
path3 xyplaneRot = (a,a,0)--(-a-2,a,0)--(-a-2,-a,0)--(a,-a,0)--cycle;
path3 xyplaneRotated = rotate(angle=-VarPhi*180/pi, u=(a,a,0), v=(a,-a,0))*xyplaneRot;

real Radius = 5;
path3 CircleOriginal = shift(Z*a*tan(VarPhi))*rotate(angle=VarPhi*180/pi, Y)*circle(c=O, r=Radius, normal=Z); 
path3 CircleProjection = xscale3(cos(VarPhi))*circle(c=O, r=Radius, normal=Z);

//%============ Drawing ===================
//Axes
draw(O--10X, red);
draw(O--10Y, blue);
draw(O--10Z, green);

//Planes
draw(surface(xyplane),black+opacity(.1));
draw(xyplane,black+linewidth(.1));
draw(surface(xyplaneRotated),black+opacity(.1));
draw(xyplaneRotated,black+linewidth(.1));


//Circular bases
draw(CircleOriginal, red);
draw(CircleProjection, red);

//Surface

draw(CircleOriginal, red);
draw(CircleProjection, red);

draw(extrude(CircleOriginal, CircleProjection),surfacepen=grey+opacity(0.3));


\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]